# DotNet Core Identity - relationship users table to custom table

Tags: asp.net-core, identity

I have back-end app in dotnet core web api. I would like to create relationship (one to many) between users table (AspNetUsers) and custom table Transactions.

I use CodeFirst approach and my db context tooks like that:

```
public class PaszoDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=PaszoDataBase.db"); 
    }

    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Where can I add property to bound User to Transactions:

```
public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
```

Comment: Im not sure if you can override OnModelCreating? If that's the case you can your manage your relations as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create your `User` class and use it in `IdentityDbContext`.
By default Identity will use `IdentityUser<string>` model for users.

If you want to change the Id type or add some other property and relations, You can do this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<Guid> //specify your database primary key type. in this case GUID or uniqueidentifier
{
    //add your properties like Birthday, RegisterDate, etc.

    //add your relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

and in your DbContext:

```
public class PaszoDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> //specify your custom class
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<PaszoDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        //Your customiziations
    }

    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```